# Subviews added programmatically to UIView in storyboards does not responds to action

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller, xcode4.2, uistoryboard

I have a scroll view with many elements that I had to build as a separate xib because Storyboards graphic interface was clipping it and made me impossible to work with.

The xib is built with interface builder, setting the file's owner graphically to the same view controller allow me to ctrl-click and link between buttons and methods in it.

The view is added like this in the viewDidLoad method:

```
UIView *w = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MainView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[self.myView.subviewolder addSubview:w];
```

where myView is the main view and subviewHolder is UIScrollView the container, both of them are linked to the controller, and the subview get added and display just fine. Self is of course the view controller.

What seems to not responds are the actions in view controller linked to the UIButtons I have in the subviews. I have put some breakpoints but the flow is just not passing there.

What am I missing ?

thanks

Comment: What are the actions from the buttons connected to in the nib file?

Comment: They are standard (IBAction) methods.

Comment: Yes, but what have you connected them to? Files owner, an object in the nib...?

Comment: I hope I understand correctly, as specified in the question file's owner is set as the same view controller, and the outlet are connected to it

Comment: Ok, I get you now. I was being a bit dumb there, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was really simple, what I did wrong is to declare subviewholder much more smaller in height than the added subviews. 
I thought that subviewholder would act as a placeholder, but instead it was causing the subviews to be displayed correctly but 'clipped' for what concerning the user interaction, therefore the IBAction was never called.